# Javascript Decode

Tags: javascript, decode

can someone help me decode this code? i want to read it by text or anything i can read:

```
var _$_986e = ["\x62\x65\x74\x74\x69\x6E\x67\x2D\x76\x69\x65\x77", "\x67\x65\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x42\x79\x49\x64", "\x62\x6F\x74\x6D\x61\x69\x6E\x66\x6F\x72\x6D\x31", "\x23\x68\x6F\x72\x69\x7A\x6F\x6E\x74\x61\x6C\x20\x3E\x20\x74\x61\x62\x6C\x65\x20\x3E\x20\x74\x62\x6F\x64\x79\x20\x3E\x20\x74\x72\x3A\x6E\x74\x68\x2D\x63\x68\x69\x6C\x64\x28\x31\x29\x20\x3E\x20\x74\x64\x20\x3E\x20\x64\x69\x76\x20\x3E\x20\x74\x61\x62\x6C\x65\x20\x3E\x20\x74\x62\x6F\x64\x79\x20\x3E\x20\x74\x72\x20\x3E\x20\x74\x64\x2E\x74\x65\x78\x74\x2D\x72\x69\x67\x68\x74\x20\x3E\x20\x62", "\x71\x75\x65\x72\x79\x53\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x6F\x72", "\x23\x76\x65\x72\x74\x69\x63\x61\x6C\x20\x3E\x20\x74\x61\x62\x6C\x65\x20\x3E\x20\x74\x62\x6F\x64\x79\x20\x3E\x20\x74\x72\x3A\x6E\x74\x68\x2D\x63\x68\x69\x6C\x64\x28\x31\x29\x20\x3E\x20\x74\x64\x20\x3E\x20\x64\x69\x76\x20\x3E\x20\x74\x61\x62\x6C\x65\x20\x3E\x20\x74\x62\x6F\x64\x79\x20\x3E\x20\x74\x72\x3A\x6E\x74\x68\x2D\x63\x68\x69\x6C\x64\x28\x31\x29\x20\x3E\x20\x74\x64\x2E\x74\x65\x78\x74\x2D\x72\x69\x67\x68\x74\x20\x3E\x20\x62", "\x76\x61\x6C\x75\x65", "\x74\x65\x78\x74\x6C\x6F\x67\x73", "\x41\x49\x43\x4F\x49\x4E\x20\x41\x75\x74\x6F\x20\x54\x72\x61\x64\x65\x20\x4C\x4F\x47\x53", "\x42\x6F\x74\x20\x4F\x70\x65\x6E\x6E\x65\x64\x21\x21\x21"];
```

The method:

```
setInterval(function() {
 if (document[_$_986e[1]](_$_986e[0]) != null) {
  var _0x187E6 = document[_$_986e[1]](_$_986e[2]);
  if (_0x187E6 == null) {
   var _0x18789 = document[_$_986e[4]](_$_986e[3]);
   if (_0x18789 == null) {
    _0x18789 = document[_$_986e[4]](_$_986e[5])
   };
   Sabto();
   setTimeout(function() {
    document[_$_986e[1]](_$_986e[7])[_$_986e[6]] = _$_986e[8];
    updateLogs(_$_986e[9]);
    updateProfiles()
   }, 2000);
   updateProfiles()
  } else {
   setTimeout(StartBot(), 500)
  }
 }
}, 1000)
```

Thanks so much. <3

Comment: Format the code!

Answer (score 0):

Your obfuscated code is semantically equivalent to:

```
setInterval(function() {
    if (document["getElementById"]("betting-view") != null) {
        if (document["getElementById"]("botmainform1") == null) {
            if (document["querySelector"]("#horizontal > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td > div > table > tbody > tr > td.text-right > b") == null) {
                document["querySelector"]("#horizontal > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td > div > table > tbody > tr > td.text-right > b") =     
                document["querySelector"]("#vertical > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td.text-right > b");
            };
            Sabto();
            setTimeout(function() {
                document["getElementById"]("textlogs")["value"] = "AICOIN Auto Trade LOGS";
                updateLogs("Bot Openned!!!");
                updateProfiles()
            }, 2000);
            updateProfiles()
        } else {
            setTimeout(StartBot(), 500)
        }
    }
}, 1000)
```